# HTML/CSS: Gradient transition from dynamic content to background on iPad. See live example

Tags: html, css, ipad

Here is an example of how I am currently implementing this functionality:

[EXAMPLE](http://signdesignllc.net/fixed%20position.html)

The content div can change in height dynamically when items are added or removed so I need the gradient to move with it. This works great in desktop browsers... However when you view it on an iPad and scroll down (moving the entire body up) it looks strange because of the position:fixed on the gradient div. Note that this is only a problem when the content div is smaller than the viewport. If the content div is larger than the viewport it pushes the gradient out of view and works great.

Is there any way to prevent the iPad from moving the body around like that or is there a better way to implement this functionality without using position: fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a bit more what looks wrong on the iPad, I don't have one with me. Also, I removed the position: fixed; and the functionality didn't change on chrome. position static and relative work the same for me.

Comment: oops, i think i am supposed to post this type of thing in the comment section. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the gradient div and instead set a min-height on the content div with a background image of the gradient with the following properties:

```
#content {
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(../Images/content-background.png);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```